# Jquery backstretch doesn't work on div except for the body element

Tags: jquery, html, element

I've seen a lot of on this topic mais no clear answer . Does Jquery backstrech support a declaration inside a DIV element.

this works

```
$.backstretch(imgSrcPath); // attaching to the body element ?
```

but declaring inside a DIV element, doesn't work.

```
$("#content").backstretch(imgSrcPath); // by id element
or
$(".Content").backstretch(imgSrcPath); // by class name
```

a DIV "content" is defined in the html page inside the body element

```
<div id="content" class="Content"/></div>
```

The Jquery components are defined as bellow in the HTML page

the shopping.js script. Note that imgsrc contains the path to a single image on the server side. For remider this works when defined on the body element $.backstrech ... and not my for example $("#content")

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

......
            $.backstretch(imgsrc});

.....

    });
```

could anybody state on that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/), the jQuery plugin, it allows you to

> [...] add a dynamically-resized, slideshow-capable background image to any page or element.

The demo for adding a backstretch to an element looks like this:

```
$("#demo").backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
```

So yes, it should work. Why it's not working for you, it's hard to know, you'll have to include more code demonstrating the issue.

---

I made a codepen following your edit to your question, and it works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNPdWq

There is an obvious typo in your document.ready-function though, remove the `}` and you should be good to go.